# npm ERR! code E404 while installing react packages

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datepicker, nivo-react

While building a Typescript based fullstack project i am getting the following error

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@mui%2ficon-material - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@mui/icon-material@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

How can I solve it?

I was trying to run the following in terminal

```
npm i react-datepicker react-router-dom@6 @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled @mui/icon-material @mui/x-data-grid @nivo/core @nivo/bar @nivo/geo @nivo/pie
```

I was expecting the installation of datepicker graphs and other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name is [`@mui/icons-material`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/icons-material) (with an `s` at `icons`).